# Returning the array of objects with specific value in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
"persons": [    
       {    
         "_id": 1,
         "name": "Joe"
       }
       {
         "_id": 1,
         "name": "Doe",
       }
       {
         "_id": 2,
         "name": "Alan"
       }
    ]
```

I am having a very big problem. How can I return all two objects having the `_id: 1` in the MongoDBDB document.
Please Help me..

Comment: Please share the attempted code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Isn't `_id` supposed to be unique in mongo? How were you able to push 2 documents in mongo with the same `_id`?

Comment: exactly cannot have duplicate _id instead use any other name

Comment: such a document cannot exist

Answer (score 0):

Usually for finding something in mongodb, you use [find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/).

```
db.persons.find({ _id: 1 });
```

But having multiple id`s with the same value is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.persons.find( { _id: 1 } )
```

Please keep collections name as singular.